# What we need to do when a new minor/major version is released for .NET 6.0, for our ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC project

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

We have a ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web project. Now based on this link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 Microsoft keeps releasing security updates for .NET 6.0. so, from a development point of view, how we need to adopt those security patches inside our projects?

Should we for example do the following:

1. Install the related .NET 6.0 release on the hosting server
2. Then update our project `program.cs` to reference the new version?

Second question, for some projects we chose to host the .NET 6.0 in Azure. Will Azure also provide all those minor versions in time?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security update is for the SDK and the host bundles, for existing project inside your development environment, it will not change.

So inside the local development environment, there is no need to do anything, just update the VS to newest version, it will use the newest .NET Core version automatically.

For the Azure environment, if you are using the VM, you should install the newest hosting bundle and then the server will use the newest version automatically.

For the Azure web app, the Azure web app will update the .NET Core version automatically.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but if a new version of .NET core got installed inside the server, should not we update the .net core version inside our project `program.cs` file? for example  to reflect the new minor version as `<TargetFramework>net6.0.16</TargetFramework>` instead of `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`??

Comment: No need, it will auto use the newest version.

Comment: so you mean as long as the updates are within version 6.0 we do not need to update the referecne inside the `program.cs`, we only need to do so , if we need to use a new .net version say 7.0 or 8.0 ?

Comment: so for example  if the server has ` 6.0.16` version and my csproj file has this framework `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` then it is fine? and my project will get the latest updates `6.0.16`?

Comment: The server is hosting bundle, the 6.0 will auto use the newest hosting bundle to run your .net core application

Comment: If you want to use .net 7, you should modify the targetFramework to the 7.0 and update your codes.